# Java Spring: Understanding @Transactional rollbackFor and transaction demarcation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, declarative, transactional

I suppose the following stacktrace as java invocation:

```
B.method2 (annotated with a plain @Transactional)
A.method1 (annotated with a plain @Transactional)
Main.main (starting point of the call, with no current transaction)
```

I expect that a transaction is started when A.method1 is entered - and the transaction will be commited (or rolled back) when A.method1 is left. I also expect that the same transaction will be used within B.method2.

A RuntimeException is thrown from within B.method2. This is a Exception that is 'listed' for rollbackFor by default. The Exception is catched within A.method1, but it will pass the boundary of @Transactional when leaving B.method2.

This is my question: Will the (current) transaction be marked for rollback or not?

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker to try it, rather than wait for someone to answer?

Comment: Actual no - because you could configure Spring with a lot of different settings (AOP, AspectJ, load-time/agent weaving...). This is a question toward the concept of @Transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default propagation mode is `REQUIRED` and method2 will use transaction started for method1. On exception this transaction will be marked for rollback, so nothing will be committed to the database. You may get `UnexpectedRollbackException` after method1.

This is not a desired behavior since code which started the transaction (owns it) should be in control of rollback/commit. I would reorganize your code to avoid such possibility.

Comment: Yes, this is what I get when trying it and also what I see when reading the Spring source code. But IMHO, it feels strange. Actually, what I expected is that the transaction is marked for rollback only if the exception 'crosses' a transaction bound. This is not the case in my example (as the transaction begins and ends in A.method1) - hence I have expected the transaction is _not_ marked for rollback.

Comment: BTW, is this handling in line with declarative transaction management in JEE 6?

Comment: @aanno What is your question then? There is only one transaction in described scenario. If it's marked for rollback, it will be rolled back. I haven't used JPA, you may want to ask another question.

Comment: The question is simple: When using JEE declarative transaction management, will the handling of Exception be similiar to this (Spring, @Transactional)?